# Saving timestamp format as a Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am saving Stripe's billing end period to the database and by default it saves as Epoch timestamp `1441292360`. How can I save it as YYYY-MM-DD in the Subscriptions table for the `cancellation_date` column?

Subscription model:

```
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email

  def save_with_stripe_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    self.cancellation_date = customer.subscriptions.first.current_period_end
    save!
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

Comment: Convert it to a string? But why? If nothing else I'd consider saving it as a timestamp or date.

Comment: Original migration had it as a string `add_column :subscriptions, :cancellation_date, :string`. Saving it as date was the question I had, as how would I save it as a date.

Comment: No, you asked how you could save it as `YYYY-MM-DD`, which isn't a date, it's a specific representation of a date. In any case, Mohamed's answer is correct: convert it to a date as he showed.

Comment: Ok my apologizes for the confusion. I don't see any answers for the question. If it's showing on your browser can you post it in the comments here?

Comment: It was deleted by Mohammed after your comment. ptd's answer shows the identical conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have unix time, you can convert it to a ruby `Time` object by running `Time.at(unix_time_integer)`. To do a conversion to a date, you could run `Time.at(unix_time_integer).to_date`.